# Using subscription to get response data in Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, kotlin-multiplatform

I am currently working on a project in KMM that uses Apollo graphql as backend and kmm as front. I am supposed to create a subscription that listens for data and do something with that data. I have gone trough documentation and any other available site online and none of the things i saw worked for me. I am new to this so i am not sure if i'm missing something or what?

I just want to mention that using Apollo sandbox works just fine as it should, so there arent any problems on backend, i am just not sure how to connect

I have ApolloClient.kt that is in shared folder in which i have tried this:

```
    val apolloClient = ApolloClient.Builder()
        .serverUrl("http://10.0.2.2:4000/graphql")
        //for web socket url i have tried using ws/wss/http
        .webSocketServerUrl("ws://10.0.2.2:4000/graphql")
        .wsProtocol(GraphQLWsProtocol.Factory())
        .build()
```

Then i have tried creating a method in same file:

```
    suspend fun subscribing() {
        val mySubscription = apolloClient.subscription(SubscribeToCarSubscription())
        val myscndsub = mySubscription.toFlow()
             myscndsub.collect {item -> println(item)
                 println("inside sub")
                 it.data?.commandResponse?.commandName
             }
    }
```

I have tried a few thing inside .collect but i think it seems that the code doesn't really go into the .collect and i am not sure why, no matter what i put inside.

this is my subscription:

```
subscription subscribeToCar {
    commandResponse {
        commandName
        value
    }
}
```

Then I tried inside my loginactivity.kt where the user logs in put this:

```
launch{
repo.subscribing()
}
```